# Buildbot set and obfuscate password set as build property

Tags: continuous-integration, buildbot

I want to pass a password to a buildstep via build properties http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/configuration/schedulers.html#forcescheduler-scheduler but I do not want the password to show up in the build properties tab or any logs.

I know that there is a secrets provider http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/secretsmanagement.html but I want/need to set a different password for every build.
I also stumbled across this code http://docs.buildbot.net/current/developer/secrets.html#secret-obfuscation
but I'm unsure if I can use it with build properties.

Comment: To remove the password from the build properties tab you can overwrite the corresponding build property after you've used it. The build properties tab only shows the last value of a build property. Note that I wouldn't do that with a sensitive password :-) I have never used the secrets API and cannot help you with that. Good luck!